# next_post_link() function give same URL of post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When I am writing below code for recent posts and then after I write code for next and previous link then that function will give me same link of post. If I am comment out "**$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);**" This line then It'll print next post link. How can I resolved this error ? please help me.

```
                <?php
                    //for use in the loop, list 5 post titles related to first tag on current post

                    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
                    if ($tags) {
                      echo '<div class="articlecontent font16 bold fontgray">Related Posts</div>';
                      $first_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;
                      $args=array(
                        'tag__in' => array($first_tag),
                        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                        'showposts'=>5,
                        'caller_get_posts'=>1
                       );
                      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                      if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                        echo '<div class="articlecontent"><ul>';
                        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                          <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                          <?php
                        endwhile;
                        echo "</ul></div>";
                      }
                    }
                ?>   

                <div class="nextprevbar">
                    <div class="prevtopic"><?php

                        previous_post_link( '%link', '<img border="0" alt="" src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/prev-bullet.gif">' . _x( '&nbsp;', 'Previous post link', 'twentyten' ) . ' %title' ); ?></div>
                    <div class="nexttopic"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title &nbsp;<img border="0" alt="" src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/next-bullet.gif">' . _x( '&nbsp;', 'Next post link', 'twentyten' ) . '</span>' ); ?></div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem has to be in the `$post` variable. Before this line is executed:

```
 while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
```

the `$post` var holds the current post data (I guess this code is inside single.php?). But after this line, and inside the loop, the `$post` var holds your various recent posts, one by one (you setup the `$post` variable when you call `the_post()` ).

After that loop (bellow the `endwhile`), `$post` will hold the data of the last post retrieved in that loop.

`previous_post_link()` and `next_post_link()` need to access `$post` for reference of the current post, but they are taking as reference the last post of your recent posts, instead of the post being read by your user.

I don't know what the html structure of this page is, but I would put the recent posts list AFTER the navigation links (next, previous posts). That would solve the problem if I am right, and in my opinion it would be semantically clearer.

Or you could also try this:

Add this line:

```
$currentPost = clone $post;
```

Before:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

And add this line:

```
<?php $post = $currentPost; ?>
```

Before you call next and previous post links functions.